# Android Studio Fails To Launch On Windows 7 x64

Tags: android, android-studio

[image]

I installed Android Studio but the below error is being displayed on start-up .

I had multiple versions of Java `JDK` installed on my system. i.e `JDK 1.6` (64 bit), `JDK 1.8` (both 64 bit and 32 bit).

I had also set the java_home path to (`E:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_31\`) 64 bit but some how android studio is showing error as it is using `JVM path` as `jdk_1.6.0_12\jre` (shown in image )

Any help is appreciated on how to make Android start up without uninstalling any `JDK` version.

[image]

Comment: try to restart your PC.

Comment: Try setting `JDK_HOME` also to the above path along with `JAVA_HOME` and ensure you are starting studio64.exe and not studio.exe

Comment: tried JDK_HOME too. Still same error.

Comment: Please do away with old and redundant versions of `JDK` and `JRE`

Comment: Can you just try an `echo %path%` in the `command prompt` and tell us the output ?

Comment: E:\Users\JOHNY>echo %path%
E:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;E:\Windows\system32;E:\Wi
ndows;E:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.0.4\bin;E:\Windows\system32\gs\gs7.05\bin;E:\Program Files (x86)\Heroku\bin;E:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_
31\bin;

Comment: I think you should remove `Java 1.6` from your computer

Comment: Finally have to end up with unistalling java 1.6 and its working now.

Comment: Cheers! I told you :D

Answer (score 0):

Just change your path in this order: 64bit java path first and later 32bit java path.

Answer (score 0):

Finally have to end up with unistalling java 1.6